# Interforest migration

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, migration

We are tasked with performing a Server 2003 interforest domain migration and AD environment.

Can the hive recommend some good documentation for the process?

More specifically migratin the user logon scipts? But any references will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory Migration Tool (google admt 3.2) will do a lot of legwork for you in terms of user/computer account migration (including deploying agents to remotely reboot computers to join a new domain!). You just need to ensure an forest-level trust is in place.

As for the scripts (how many??), i'd just take a copy of them and redeploy them on the new domain.

Comment: yeah we've been doing some reading on the tool and testing it in a VM.  the one issue seems to be getting permissions to right when using the tool - we did not have domain admin rights for the workstations that the agents were being deployed to.  Perhaps a group policy could allow it to run as a local user?

Comment: well specifically for the remote domain join you'll need domain admin rights anyway not local. it was a while ago when i did this (NT4->2003). you'll need at least 3 VMs to do a proper simulation...